# How to test auto-renewable subscription for expiration on specified time iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have integrated auto renewable subscription and its done, but how do i test when it expires because it requires atleast 7 days for subscription expiry.

I need to test it by specifying 5 mins or any specific time. We can't wait for 7 days to get subscription expired in sandbox.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In the sandbox, all auto-renewing durations have been shortened to just a few minutes (and they only renew 5 times).  So you don't have to wait 7 days to test for renewal.  You should test frequently in the sandbox, to see if there are any new receipts.